# Tool/Product for Internal Web Services Registry

Tags: wcf, web-services, registry, metadata, asmx

We have a ton of webservices - asmx & WCF services in our staggered enterprise.

I would like to centralize cetain information about them in the form of  a dictionary. Information

- like: What it does - plain english version
- Where it is deployed
- Sample input feeds etc...

Is there a tool to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [WSO2 Governance Registry](http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/) (Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with the company).